matlab bifurcation plot
i'm trying to plot a bifurcation diagram for discrete dynamical system
which is
$$\begin{cases}
X_{n + 1} = a X_n (1 - X_n) - X_n Y_n \\
Y_{n + 1} = -c Y_n + d X_n Y_n
\end{cases}$$
where $a = 3.5$, $c = 0.2$, $d = 1.92$ where $1.4 \le d \le 2.4$ and and the initial condition is $x_1 = 0.6$, $y_1 = 0.3$
i should get exact that picture
enter image description here
my code in matlab is
            for d=1.92:1.4:2.4;
                X(1)=0.6; 
                Y(1)=0.3;
                a=3.5; 
                c=0.2;
            for t=1:10000;
                X(t+1)=a*X(t)*(1-X(t))- 
                                 (X(t)*Y(t));  
                Y(t+1)=-c*Y(t)+d*X(t)*Y(t); 
            end
            for  t=1:10000;
                plot(d,X(t),'k.','markersize',8);
                xlabel('d')
                ylabel('x(n)')

            end
            hold on
            end  

what i'm getting is just a point
enter image description here
any help please

Please refrain from using image links in your question. With regards to your simulation, how many values of $d$ are being analyzed?

@K.Jiang d = 1.92 and d between 1.4 and 2.4

The problem is that when you use something like d = 1.92:1.4:2.4, it roughly means "step $d$ in increments of $1.4$ between $1.92$ and $2.4$". This does not sound like what you want.

The main problem is here:

for d=1.92:1.4:2.4;

See MATLAB's documentation for colon syntax. Your iteration only has one element, namely, $d = 1.92$, because $1.92 + 1.4 > 2.4$. However, if you want to sweep multiple values of $d$, so something like d = linspace(1.4, 2.4) is more appropriate. See MATLAB's documentation for more information about linspace. It's important to know that the exact value $d = 1.92$ may not appear in this array, but if you really wanted to analyze it, you can manually add it to your array.
The next issue is here:
        for  t=1:10000;
            plot(d,X(t),'k.','markersize',8);
            xlabel('d')
            ylabel('x(n)')

        end

This is problematic because when you plot the bifurcation diagram, you want to mark the orbits of the system. A typical trick to making such diagrams is to let the system evolve / equilibrate over a "long" time, then save the trajectory after then. Since you are saving the entire trajectory, you should just plot the end of it.
If you fix the problems above, you will end up with something like the following:

Note that you do not see the chaotic behavior near the critical value of $d$, and this is because we are only tracking one initial condition.

Thanks for the explanation , but i didn't understand the second issue can i have more explanation, and there is a way so i can write a code to specify the value of d = 1.92 ?

and how can i see the chaotic behavior any help please ?

@user1325291 The diagram sweeps $d$; you want to plot more than just $d = 1.92$. To observe the chaotic behavior, try using a variety of initial conditions rather than just $x_1 = 0.6$ and $y_1 = 0.3$. For the given initial conditions, you can show that for $d < d^* \approx 1.92$, the trajectory tends to four values of $x$ that are about $0.38, 0.5, 0.83, 0.87$, while for $d > d^*$, there is one stable $x$ (that decreases with $d$).

Good didactic explanations.

@K.Jiang can you help me how to write a code for a variety initial conditions ?  Sorry for my  many questions but I’m new to these things and I’m trying to understand as much as I can and thank you.

@JeanMarie any help please ?

see here.

@user1325291 Where did you get the plot you are trying to reproduce? You can check the details there.

@K.Jiang i got it from research, unfortunately there is no explanation for any code.

@user1325291 Is it from a paper? You don't necessarily need code.

@K.Jiang Yes, but I need to understand how to plot the bifurcation diagram in general not only for that case, for now i got the diagram but i didn't reach to a result of how to see the chaotic behaviour

@user1325291 What is that paper?
